# Add to Cart Button all on same height - Shopify debut

Tags: html, css, forms, themes, shopify

So I added the following code to the shoopify debut theme to allow me to instantly add the products to the cart:

```
<form method="post" action="/cart/add">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}" />
  <input min="1" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" style="width:65px; padding: 9px 10px; vertical-align: top; margin-top:-30px;"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn" style="padding: 10px 10px; vertical-align: top; margin-top:-30px;"/>
</form>
```

Which looks something like this:
[add to cart button example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y2gR.png)

But I couldn't figure out how to set these "add to cart" fields all on the same height. They are using top-margin to define their position under the product grid. But the images and product descriptions aren't all the same height and lenghts which gives me these unaligned buttons.

Is there still a way that I can align them all on the same height?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You have to use flexbox for this.

Use display: flex; align-items: flex-end; in the parent wrapper of all cards.

Comment: Or share your site url if you want us to give you the exact solution.

Comment: Thanks. This is the url: https://www.discover.snow-pearl.com/collections/alle-produkte

Comment: you need to add the min-height to images on the collections listing page, they are not equal height. or use JS lib like to [Match Height](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height)

Comment: and what do I do about the different text lengths (1 or 2 lines)? Plus when the product is on sale there is a sale-badge that pushes down my "add to cart" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a pretty simple solution. I used the comment from Mohd Salman. This pointed me to the right correction but it didn't work as wished.

So I searched the parent element in the theme.css code (assets section) and found the following one:

```
.grid--view-items {
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: -35px; }
```

Then I added some flex code and the final version looks like this:

```
.grid--view-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: -35px; }
```

Thanks to Mohd Salman, for pointing me in the right direction.